# How to properly override operator [] of MapBase

Tags: dart

I created a simple class, extending `MapBase<String, String>`. All looks well, except the `operator []` override. This is the code:

```
class MyMap extends MapBase<String, String> {

  Map<String, String> _map = {};

  @override
  Iterable<String> get keys => _map.keys;

  @override
  String remove(Object key) => _map.remove(key);

  @override
  void clear() => _map.clear();

  @override
  operator []= (String key, String value) => _map[key] = value;

  @override
  String operator [] (String key) => _map[key];
}
```

The `@override operator []` results in the following error:

```
error: 'MyMap.[]' ('(String) → String') isn't a valid override of 'Map.[]' ('(Object) → String'). (invalid_override at [joap] lib\api\api_query.dart:43)ˋ
error: 'MyMap.[]' ('(String) → String') isn't a valid override of 'MapMixin.[]' ('(Object) → String'). (invalid_override at [joap] lib\api\api_query.dart:43)
```

I find this strange, because the `@override operator []=` does not show this error. Removing the `String` type from the `key` parameter resolves the problem.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure why the back ticks don't work as expected. Sorry for that.

Comment: I fixed the formatting.  The `ˋ` character (U+02CB) is not the `\`` character (U+0060). (They are [homoglyphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homoglyph).)

Comment: Thanx. Shall try to find out what's wrong with my RDP keyboard settings and fix that.

Answer (score 1):

The signature for your `operator[]` override doesn't match the base signature.

`Map`'s [`operator[]`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-collection/MapMixin/operator_get.html) takes an `Object` argument, not the type of the `Key`. (In contrast, [`operator[]=`](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.2.0/dart-collection/MapMixin/operator_put.html) *does* take the `Key` type as its argument.)

(I found this surprising, but there is [rationale for it](https://github.com/dart-lang/linter/issues/1307#issuecomment-474051122).)

Comment: Thanx for the reply, although I'm having trouble understanding that rationale. But that's because I'm not that fast and probably need to read it a couple of times more :)

Comment: @Pieter-JandeVries The rationale is essentially that Java does something similar, which is that if you have a collection of apples, then if you ask if it contains an orange, the answer will be "no" (because it doesn't) instead of generating an error.  That is, it's not an error to ask stupid questions.

Comment: Thanx again James. The mere fact that Java does it like this, is not really a good reason. It also does not explain why the `key` parameter for `operator []=` is handled differently than the one for `operator []`. In this particular case, I *explicitly* extend `MapBase<String, String>`, intending to declare a strict interface, accepting only strings as valid key values. So I still don't understand why my implementation does not accept a `String` as the `key`. After all, I have a collection of apples and simply ask for a specific apple. Or am I still missing something completely here?

Comment: `operator[]=` must take a `Key` because trying to insert a key of the wrong type would violate the container.  A container declared to contains only apples cannot contain oranges, but the answer to whether that container contains an orange is always "no". (Note that *I* don't agree with `operator[]` taking `Object`.) As for why your implementation can't work, it's because the language does not support overloaded methods, so overrides *must* match the base method's signature exactly.

Comment: Aha! I was not aware of the not supported operator overloads. It's a shame but at least it makes sense to me now. Thanks for your help and patience.